# sha256 encryption in raw javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, sha256, coinbase-api

I'm trying to encrypt a string to HMAC SHA256 within raw javascript using a [web-hosted library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha256/0.9.0/sha256.js) but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm trying to do this to call the [Coinbase API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#api-key). You need to give a few values with the GET request including a Signature, which is where I am experiencing problems. The signature needs to be HMAC SHA256 encrypted. The signature should include the following:

> The `CB-ACCESS-SIGN` header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using the secret key on the prehash string `timestamp + method + requestPath + body` (where + represents string concatenation). The timestamp value is the same as the `CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP` header.
>
> The `body` is the request body string or omitted if there is no request body (typically for GET requests).
>
> The `method` should be UPPER CASE.

What I think they are saying is that I can leave out the body because it's a GET request.

My code is the following:

The HTML library call:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha256/0.9.0/sha256.js"></script>
```

The Javascript Encryption and GET request:

```
url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts"
var xmlHttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp1.open( "GET", "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/time", false);
xmlHttp1.send( null )
ts = xmlHttp1.responseText;
var ts1 = JSON.parse(ts)
var message = ts1.data.epoch + "GET" + url + ""
sha256(message);
var hash = sha256.hmac.create('key');

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("CB-ACCESS-KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", ts1.data.epoch);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", hash);
xmlHttp.send( null );
```

The coinbase API is responding with:

```
{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}
```

meaning that everything is correct, except for the signature.

Comment: Refer to https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication, it seems like the url path they used in message is relative but you provide a absolute path. Not sure if this is the problem but you can inspect your code to compare the your hash function can create same output with whatever library they are using.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I came across this myself a couple of minutes ago, but that was indeed one of the problems. Thank you.

Comment: HMAC is not encryption. It is Hash-based Message Authentication Code!

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah I don't know much about encryption, so I didn't know that. Thank you for the information however!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out myself (Yunhai also saw 1 of the problems).

The problems were:

- The HMAC encryption needed my API_SECRET
- I needed to use the URL Parameters, not the entire URL.